# What does ともあれ解析-待ちかな～ mean?

Tags: translation

Context: A dangerous crisis is happening, and the boss man has just received partial report on the entire incident, but enough to be informed what's going on. The full report is waiting on some labatory analysis of leftovers from previous incident in the crisis.

After the subordinate who reported leaves, his aide says:

> ともあれ解析待ちかな～

I'm assuming this is ともあれ/解析/待ち/かな～ and the aide is wondering if they should wait for the full (complete) report. Am I right here? The big boss answers:

> あぁ
>
> 対策をして挑まないと同じ轍を踏むことになる

I'm guessing that Aaa, is less him saying they should wait but more exasperation because he thinks they need to start making countermeasures now or the same thing will happen again.

Of course it could be a confirmation and mean "Yes, we need to prepare properly or else things will take the same course."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

待ち after a suru-verb/noun works as a suffix that forms a no-adjective. It means "waiting for ～".

> - 開店待ちの行列
> - 今【いま】何【なに】待ち【まち】？
>     (informal) What are we waiting for?

So ともあれ解析待ちかな means "Anyway, I guess we have to wait for the (full) analysis." かな (and か) means "I wonder if" or "I guess" depending on the intonation, but when かな is written like this, you have to guess from the context. あぁ here simply means "Yeah (we have to wait)".